# need memoized function to quack like a function

Tags: python, memoization

In a bit of my code I'm using the nice [memoized](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) class from the Python Decorator Library.

One of the libraries I'm using uses introspection on a function to get the number of arguments it takes, and fails on the decorated function. Specifically, it checks the `co_argcount` variable.

```
if (PyInt_AsLong(co_argcount) < 1) {
      PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "This function has no parameters to mini\
mize.");
```

It seems the argcount isn't being transferred to the memoized function.

```
>>> def f(x):
...     return x
... 
>>> f.func_code.co_argcount
1
>>> g = memoized(f)
>>> g.func_code.co_argcount
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'memoized' object has no attribute 'func_code'
```

How can I modify the memoized class so that my memoized functions look, taste, and smell like the original function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a *signature-preserving decorator*.  The easiest way to do that is to use the library http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator which takes care of preserving the signature for you.

The internals of the library are quite ugly (it uses *`exec`*!) but it encapsulates them quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Add that to your `memoized` class

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name.startswith('func_'):
        return getattr(self.func, name)
    raise AttributeError
```

So it'll pass attribute lookup for `func_...` to the original function.

Maybe you will also want to write a `__setattr__` function to deny writing these attributes, but it's not necessary if you know you won't try to change the values.